# How to compare two .ear files recursively

Tags: diff, compare, ear

I'm modifying a build process and I need to do a complete comparison of the contents of two `.ear` files. That means recursively comparing each archive in the `.ear`. These `.ear` files have archives that contain archives.

I've looked at Beyond Compare and Archive Analyzer, but they only do one level at a time. I have to manually drill down into each archive.  I'm looking for something more automatic.

Eclipse and UltraCompare do a binary comparison of the two .ears which is not what I want.

How can I compare two `.ear` files recursively?

Comment: I'd suggest contacting Beyond Compare support. They are very responsive in my experience, and may be able to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem turned out to be more than just expanding the .ear file recursively (I wrote a Java class to do that - recursion made it simple.)  Once the .ear files are expanded I have to diff the directories to check for any changes.  If anything other than timestamps changed then I know that the build is producing a different binary.

The second problem is that our build process generates hundreds of .xml files and subsequent builds re-generate those .xml files with the elements in different order.  I'm not sure why.  When I expand two .ear files made by back-to-back builds with no changes to anything the diff of the resulting directories shows hundreds of .xml files with diffs, even though they are functionally equivalent.

In addition to expanding the .ear files recursively I need to do a diff and exclude the .xml files in certain directories.  I thought that Cygwin diff would do this, but the --exclude switch doesn't recognize any path information:

[Cygwin diff won't exclude files if a directory is included in the pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619075/cygwin-diff-wont-exclude-files-if-a-directory-is-included-in-the-pattern)

If I don't find a solution to this I'll write another Java class to step through the whole directory structure doing a single level diff in each directory and excluding the .xml files in the appropriate directories.

I have the feeling that I'm re-inventing the wheel, but I can't find a wheel right now.

Comment: How about using a temporary Git repository to do the diffing?
Extract the first .ear file and add&check-in everything,
extract the second .ear file, now you can let Git do the diffing.

Comment: Thanks Max. Nice hack. I expanded ear, jar and war modules. Checked in all files and used git diff.

Answer (score 5):

[zipdiff](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zipdiff/) provides a very good open source solution.

Comment: zipdiff is nice but won't work well on Linux because MS Windows paths are expected

Answer (score 1):

In Beyond Compare go into the `Session Settings` dialog, and on the `Handling` tab is an `Archive Handling` option.  If it's set to `As folders always` BC will treat archives just like folders, so it's fully recursive.

Comment: That seems to make it work recursively, but there is no output.  All I get is a timestamp and "Successfully compared 44410 items.  Completed in 35.9 seconds."  There are some differences between the two .ear files, but they don't get reported.  If I drill down into the archive structure it shows files with differences.  I need to get a diff report without having to manually drill into the entire tree.

Comment: Assuming you're writing a script, if you just want a list of files use the `FOLDER-REPORT` command.  If you want the details within the files use `EXPAND ALL`, `SELECT DIFF.FILES NEWER.FILES OLDER.FILES ORPHAN.FILES`, then 'FILE-REPORT'.  FILE/FOLDER-REPORT both require extra parameters covered in the help.  You can write the resulting report to an HTML or plain text file.

Comment: I wasn't writing a BC script.  I decided to finally write a Java program to recursively expand a .ear file and all archives contained in it.